# how to replace the first two digits of an integer in c++?

Tags: c++, integer

I am facing the following issue.:

I have a 6-digit, positive integer value such as `120117` and I want to be able to update the first two digits (`12` in this case) to:

- 50 if that 2-digit number is less than or equal to 20
- 60 if that 2-digit number is greater than 20.

So the final output for the example above would be `500117`.

All the inputs are positive, 6-digit integers.

I know that I can convert this integer to a string and then use the `.substr` to insert the 50 or 60 in the desired location, but I do not want to use any string related operations. I only want to use arithmetic operations.

I am really lost on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: use maths.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know it has to do with some math logic, but I am unable to figure it out. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Simple arithmetic should do. Maybe start researching division..

Comment: Some modulus and divisions might help.

Comment: First count the number of digits. This can be done by using division by 10 in a loop, incrementing a counter each iteration. Then subtract two and raise the result to the power of `10`. Then divide the input value by that result. This will give you a two-digit number corresponding to the top two digits of the input number. You can use modulo instead to get the other digits.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know how to use the modulus by 10 to obtain the first digit but for the leftmost two digits, would that be mod by 100?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will try it out and let you know. Thanks alot

Comment: What do you do in situations with only 1-digit integers? What do you do with negative integers? What do you do with 0?

Comment: @John I will always have input in a length of 6 digits and only positive numbers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried your logic but it doesnt work, can you put a pseudocode?

Comment: *I will always have input in a length of 6 digits and only positive numbers.* – ... and why didn't you tell that in the beginning? that makes it trivial.

Comment: @Angelina he meant to 1) find the numbers of digits (call this N), 2) find 10^(N-2) (call this X), 3) divide your original number by X. In total, this will give you a 2-digit base-10 integer that represents the top two digits. But yes, J. Doe is right, if you always have 6-digit inputs then just divide by 10000 to find if the first two digits are less than 20 or more than 20.

Comment: @Angelina -- What is `120117 / 10000` and remove the decimals?  See something that gives you a hint?

Comment: Also, what is supposed to be done if the first 2 digits are `20`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see that it gives me the first two digits which are 12 but how do I then update the 12 to ```50``` to give me ```500117``` ? That part I am lost as I dont want to use string operation

Comment: @John If it is 20 it should replace it to 50. See recent edits.

Comment: @Angelina -- It's stated in your assignment, almost programmatically.  "If the number is x, change the number to y, else change it to z".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It has either of the two assignments only.

Comment: You can mathematically remove the first two digits by subtracting `(first-two-digits)*10^(N-2)`, in this case, `10^(N-2) is always `10,000`, then it's trivial to make the first two digits either 50 or 60 from there by adding `50,000` or `60,000`.

Comment: @John May you provide me insight on how to do that as I am really lost

Comment: @Angelina This assignment is a test of simple division, modulus, and logical thinking.  You should have been able to figure out what to do once you got those two digits (which to me would be the hard part of this assignment), but I guess not.

Comment: @John I dont think adding 50000 or 60000 works as the final result should be ```500117 ``` and using ur logic doesnt make sense. Am i missing sth?

Comment: @Angelina no you're not missing something, I'm missing a 0. It was a typo on my part. Should be 500000 or 600000.

Comment: @John ```int res = 120117/10000;
    int fin = 500000 + res;
    cout << fin;``` The output is 500012 and not 500117.

Answer (score 4):

Let I be the input (120117). Let D be the number of digits given by ⌊log<sub>10</sub>(I)⌋ + 1 <sub>Regarding your edit: You can skip this and just use 6 if the number of digits is constant</sub>. Let T be 10<sup>D - 2</sup>. Let P be I/T using integer division. This result is the first two digits. Compare this to 20 and if the predicate matches then let S be either 60 or 50 depending on result of the comparison. Let the output be I + (S - P) * T.

> Can you give a pseudocode?

```
I = 120117
D = 6
T = pow(10, D - 2)
P = I / T
S = 50 if P <= 20 else 60
return I + (S - P) * T
```

The logic here relies on the observation that multiplying a number by the radix is equivalent to "shifting" the digits left and division is equivalent to shifting right. Since we are dealing with decimal digits, we multiply and divide with 10. Repeated multiply and division with same number can be simplified into multiplying or dividing with that number to the power of the number of repetitions. That the number of digits is found by radix based logarithm also follows from the same shifting behaviour, but that is not as intuitive.

It would be simpler to use string operations though.

Comment: Can you give a pseudocode?

Comment: This type of theoretical answer *technically* answers the question, but is overly broad. The OP provided enough information that this answer could be simplified to state that you can divide the input by `10000` and compare the integer result to determine the answer. The remainder of the integer division of the input with 10000 could then be added to the answer to result in the final outcome. @Angelina because this question is now closed, it is impossible to provide a pseudocode without editing this final, remaining answer, with the author's permission, of course.

Comment: @JoelTrauger You could provide it in the comments though of what you mentioned. I am a bit lost on the second part .. ```The remainder of the integer division of the input with 10000 could then be added to the answer to result in the final outcome```

Comment: @Angelina I added a pseudocode

Comment: For instance, now if I want to do something different, like adding the 50 to the existing input, ```120117``` to make an output of ```50120117```, would your logic still work?

Comment: What would you have to add to `120117` to make it equal `50120117`? How would you obtain this information? Construct a basic algebraic equation to go from your input to your output. Reproduce this simple equation in your code using the mathematical operators `+ - * /` and any `if` statements needed for branching logic. This is a simple high-school math problem. Programming and mathematics are very closely related.

Comment: @I know it is simple as adding 50 * 10000 + input, is that right?

Comment: You are close. It's`50*1000000`. `50 * 1000000 = 50000000`. `500000000 + 120117 = 50120117`.

Comment: pow is floating-point. Mixing floating-point and integers is not sound.

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica `pow` is whatever you want it to be if you write it yourself.